# What type of markup is an XCode project?

Tags: xcode, parsing, syntax, markup

I am trying to find a parser for an xcode project, but I don't recognize the type of markup.

An example of the format:

```
// !$*UTF8*$!
{
    <KEY> = <VALUE>;
    <KEY> = <VALUE>;

    <KEY> =
    {
        <KEY> =
        {
            <KEY> = <VALUE>;
            <KEY> = <VALUE>;
            <KEY> = <VALUE>;
        };

        <KEY> = ( <VALUE>, <VALUE>, <VALUE>, <VALUE>, );
    };
}
```

What type of markup is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an old-style property list before Apple switched to xml-style property lists. You can read that in using `NSDictionary`/`NSArray` `+<dictionary/array>WithContentsOfFile:`, using the appropriate class based on if your property list's base object is an array (values separated by commas enclosed by parentheses) or a dictionary (key-value pairs enclosed by curly braces). If you get `nil` back you know you've chosen the wrong one.

`+<collection>WithContentsOfFile:` will turn the entire file into Foundation framework objects.

Comment: Definitely helps, knowing what classes one can use to read a Plist. =D

Comment: Yeah the question was a little unclear. I think both of us answered it correctly haha.

Comment: sorry Steen, but Jack's got you by 2 minutes =)

Comment: If it's about who's accepted, I think Jack's the better answer, no problem there, but I *did* "answer" first if that's what you're talking about. ;)

Comment: sorry, was just going by the time I saw on the post. I up-voted you anyways =)

Answer (score 2):

I found this, http://www.monobjc.net/index.php?page=xcode-project-file-format, which states that

> The Xcode project file is an old-style plist (Next style) based on braces to delimit the hierarchy. The file begins with an explicit encoding information, usually the UTF-8 one. This means that the file must not bear a BOM (Byte Ordering Mark) at its start or the parsing will fail.

It seems to be an attempt at reverse-engineering the full project file format.